# in VSCODE, copy and paste into a git bash shell has bad / incorrect characters

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code, clipboard, git-bash

If I have a document open in VSCode in windows, and I copy some text from a document like:
`git submodule update --init --recursive`

and I paste it into a git bash terminal in VSCODE, it has incorrect characters:
`git submodule update --init --recursiveFunction Key 9`

Is this something configured incorrectly?

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem with git bash.

I learned to **paste things to the terminal using <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>insert</kbd>**.

Since this, I had never problems with unwanted characters. I hope that solves your problem.